# How long can a Wizard hold their breath?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, breathing

For a 5e campaign, I have created the character Diogenes, a Human Wizard from the school of transmutation. [Diogenes, in real life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diogenes), is said to have [possibly died due to holding his breath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diogenes#Death) for too long.

I want to end my character in the same way, but (of course) with more pizazz. 
Without death (but unconsciousness is OK), what is the longest that a character could survive without breathing? I am speaking of a feat that only requires oneself, and no aid, but which might involve items or methods to extend the duration.

Comment: A wizard is never out of breath! he breaths precisely when he means to

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The rules for holding your breath are on page 183 of the PHB.

> A
>   creature
>   can
>   hold
>   its
>   breath
>   for
>   a
>   number
>   of
>   minutes
>   equal
>   to
>   1
>   +
>   its
>   Constitution
>   modifier
>   (minimum
>   of
>   30
>   seconds).

The easiest way to extend this is to use a Bottled Breath, from *Princes of the Apocalypse*. This will let you hold your breath for an hour. Using *Polymorph* to turn into a Plesiosaurus or a Giant Octopus will likewise let you hold your breath for an hour. If you're really serious about this, though, you should turn into an air genasi. This will let you hold your breath literally forever.

Comment: Technically, using Polymorph to turn into an air genasi will let you hold your breath until the duration of Polymorph runs out... which is an hour. If you want to go longer, you'll need True Polymorph.

Comment: @anaximander Actually, you can't use Polymorph to turn into an air genasi. It's strictly the realm of Shapechange and True Polymorph, and even then it's iffy.

Comment: Technically Air Genasi don't breath to start with, so they wouldn't technically be holding their breath anyway...

Comment: @Rycochet Er, what? Where are you getting that from? They have a trait that literally says they can hold their breath indefinitely.

Comment: @Miniman Ugh, my bad - you're totally right, I was remembering the 3rd edition Forgotten Realms book where they didn't breath at all - in 5th Players Companion they do indeed breath :-) https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/EE_PlayersCompanion.pdf

Answer (score 4):

**A PC can hold their breath for a certain duration depending on their Constitution modifier.**

As per page 183 of the PHB:

> A creature can hold its breath for a number of minutes equal to 1 + its Constitution modifier (minimum of 30 seconds).

Keeping in mind that a round is 6 seconds, hence a minute is 10 rounds, a Wizard with a standard +2 Con mod can hold their breath 3 minutes, aka 30 rounds.

If you want to extend the duration, there are some potions that allow water breathing, as well as several items in the DMG's magical items section. Also, Polymorphing into an aquatic form should do the trick, and can extend the duration for several hours depending on the number of spell slots of appropriate level available to you.

Answer (score 2):

The answer for the length of a held breath is as others have pointed out: A creature can hold its breath for a number of minutes equal to 1 + its Constitution modifier (minimum of 30 seconds).

That is only half of your question though.  If I am reading this correctly, you want to test yourself as if you were Diogenes.  I would recommend magically creating/summoning an Octopus or Giant Octopus.  Whichever has the same CON modifier as you.  They are 0 and +1 respectively.   Since  Diogenes died from holding his breath, or possibly eating an octopus, the creature could put a tentacle in your mouth.  It can only breath water, you only air.  You would both 'die' at the same time if you have the same Con modifier.  Your concentration would break, the Octopus would then be 'unsummoned', and you would be unconscious and able to make death saves as normal.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: 5e Octopus has a special ability: Hold Breath for 30 minutes.  If you summon it with a concentration spell, that's fine, it vanishes because your concentration ends, not because it dies.

Answer (score -2):

### Indefinitely.

If your wizard becomes a lich, he will be undead and therefore never have to breathe again. I don't think this helps with your situation, however.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is valid without a player character option for becoming a lich (which I'm pretty sure 5e doesn't have).

Comment: Homebrew has options

Answer (score -3):

As not stating RAW (also this subject has not been mentioned on Sage Advice), then something I have done in the past might be relevant.

In 3.5 holding your breath was a lot more complicated with limits on what you could do as well as the chance from the dice. I much prefer the simplicity of 5th, but wanted to add an element of chance to it - specifically:

> The GM calls for an ability check when a character or monster attempts an action (other than an attack) that has a chance of failure. When the outcome is uncertain, the dice determine the results.

If the GM is amenable to having saving throws afterwards (rather than the straight unconsciousness as on PHB p183) then I've given an increasing DC for each round, starting at 1 for the round after the end of the last "normal" breath (ie, 30 seconds / 5 rounds), and hitting 20 some 19 rounds later - it added an extra minute or two, but somewhat more random.

Trying not to drown while exerting yourself definitely seems like one of the times when doing things calls for a dice roll!

When I tried it this worked well enough, it took a 12 Con from exactly 60 seconds to only being sure of the first 36 seconds, with the (tiny) potential to last 2:36... It didn't last long enough for that chance to actually be relevant, but in turn based action it certainly makes things a little bit harder for players to go "Oh, I can hold my breath for 2 minutes, so I'll just fight underwater then..."

Other possibilities (not tried or tested) include:

- I want to allow a character to become proficient / get advantage in it if practised enough - think free-diving, where you might not have a high Constitution, but you can hold your breath a long time due to (very specific) training.
- If treated as a skill check could use the Foresight spell to give 8 hours of advantage.
- If treated as a saving throw then Bless could give a little help.
- If treated as either skill or saving throw then Bardic Inspiration can help.
- A single inspiration dice can be very useful against a bad roll.
- The Lucky feat can save your life (though as a GM I'd put this more against "trying to do xyz while not drowning" rather than "just holding my breath while swimming").
- Probably not a good idea to try this when Fatigued...

Comment: I think this is getting downvoted because "just change the rules" isn't a very useful answer to "how do I extend my character's ability to hold his breath?" Any question could have "just change the rules" as an answer — can you [edit] to say something about why in this case it's the *best* solution? Maybe also address the problem that the person asking isn't in charge of changing the rules (they're not the DM)?

Comment: I actually quoted where it's not changing the rules - it's coming up with some form of an ability check to allow the rules to work. Swimming is already covered via Athletics, but none of the skills are Con based, and holding your breath is specifically related to Con. The DM makes the calls for everything, so giving ideas (especially ones that have been used before) is useful. If someone with Twitter wants to ask @JeremyECrawford then they can get an official ruling on how the DM can actually call an ability check on holding their breath...